# difference between ((c=getchar())!=EOF) and ((c=getchar())!='~'),'~' can be any character

Tags: c, eof, getchar

As soon as '~' is encountered, anything after that is not printed and control comes out 
while loop

```
while((c = getchar()) != '~')
{
    putchar(c);
    printf(" ");
}
input: asdf~jkl
output: a s d f   //control is out of while loop
```

as soon as '^Z' is encountered, anything after that is not printed but control doesn't come out of while loop

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    printf(" ");
}
input: asdf^Zjkl
output a s d f ->   //control is still inside while loop
```

Please explain why is this happening?
As soon as EOF is encountered, while loop must exit, but this is not happening.
Is is necessary that (ctrl+Z) must be the first character on the new line to terminate while loop?
This has something to do with the working of getchar() and EOF (ctr+Z)

Comment: `EOF` is a 4-byte value. Typically, a variable of type `int` should be used in order to store it. Does your `c` variable happen to be of type `char`?

Comment: yes, I declared c to be int

Answer (score 2):

It's the way the console input editor works in a Windows/DOS command prompt. Input is done line by line, which is why you can go back and forth editing the characters until you press ENTER, and at that point the contents of the line are sent to the program and a new line is started.

Whoever wrote the editor in DOS decided that typing ^Z at the beginning of the line was the way to tell the editor that you're done providing input.

The thing is that EOF (end of file) is a virtual mark and not always a real character. Its actual value (-1) suggests that by being way outside the range of character codes (which is also why it's important to use an `int` variable instead of a `char` when calling `getchar()` and `fgetc()`).

In fact, your example...

```
while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    printf(" ");
}
```

...can work as you expect it if you run the program using input redirection ("program.exe  < input.txt") to feed it a file with ^Z in the middle. In that case, there is no command line editor in the way.